# Upsert data into Cassandra database using Astyanax client

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

**Problem Statement:-**

I am trying to insert data into Cassandra database. I am using `Netflix/Astyanax client` for this.

Below is the code which will `upsert` data into `Cassandra database` using `Astyanax client`.

In my below method, it accepts two parameter. One is the `userId` which I will be using as the `RowKey` and `attributes` map which will contain, `column name` as the key and it's `column value` as the value in the map.

Now how can I use `Astyanax client` to `upsert data` into Cassandra database using the below method which accepts those two parameters?

I am mainly concern about `attributes` Map. How should I use that map to `upsert` data into Cassandra database?

```
/**
 * Performs an upsert of the specified attributes for the specified id.
 */
public void upsertAttributes(final String userId, final Map<String, String> attributes) {

    MutationBatch m = CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace().prepareMutationBatch();

    m.withRow(CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getEmp_cf(), userId)
    .putColumn(attributeName from attributesMap, attributeValue from attributesMap, null)
    ;

    try {
        m.execute();
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.append("Failed to read from C* = '").append(e).append("'. ");

        LOG.error("Failed to write data to C*", e);

        throw new RuntimeException("failed to write data to C*", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost given the solution, but i think its not clear to you

```
 MutationBatch m = CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace().prepareMutationBatch();
 ColumnListMutation<String> clm = m.withRow(CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getEmp_cf(), userId);
 for(String key: attributeMap.keySet()){
     clm.putColumn(key, attributeMap.get(key), null);
 }

try {
    m.execute();
} catch (ConnectionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Basically **putColumn** has different overloaded variations, so it will support all the datatypes supported by cassandra.

Comment: Thanks abhi. That thing, I already know whatever code you posted out above. My main challenge is to get the `col1` from the `attributes Map` and `col1 value` from the same `attributesMap`. If you go through my question again, you will see what I am trying to say.

Comment: ,Basically in my attributes Map, I will have column name and corresponding column value. So I need to get the column names and column values from those map.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I guess, you are the only Cassandra folks here out. :). I have two more questions related to Cassandra open. And nobody has answered that yet. These two are related to Datastax API (new Binary protocol) [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096009/creating-column-family-or-table-in-cassandra-while-working-datastax-apiwhich-us) and [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096207/upsert-read-into-from-cassandra-database-using-datastax-api-using-new-binary-pr). If you have some time, take a look into that as well. Thanks a lot for the help.