# Spring Data Cassandra and User Defined Types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

So since 1.5, we can map UDT with @UserDefinedType. We are experiencing errors when trying to map one of these :

```
@UserDefinedType("criteria")
public class Criteria {

  @CassandraType(type = Name.VARCHAR)
  private String cle;

  @CassandraType(type = Name.VARCHAR)
  private String nom;

  @CassandraType(type = Name.VARCHAR)
  private String format;
}
```

We are getting this error at launch :

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown
>   type [class java.lang.String] for property [cle] in entity
>   [com.laposte.ariane.udt.Critere]; only primitive types and Collections
>   or Maps of primitive types are allowed

To avoid this, we removed @CassandraType annotations, but it doesn't seem right.

What's wrong with our mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataStax' driver reports only `Name.TEXT` as primitive data type but not `Name.VARCHAR` via `DataType.allPrimitiveTypes()`. Spring Data Cassandra uses `DataType.allPrimitiveTypes()` to resolve name to type mappings. I filed a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-488) to add explicit type mappings for these two.

See also:

- [Cassandra: text vs varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530230/cassandra-text-vs-varchar)